# Azure Function App fails to update Table Row

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I'm currently debugging this locally, so in VS Code, using the function app extension.

I'm testing the endpoint with Postman locally too.

I'm trying to increment a number stored in a property in a Storage account Table. Its simple enough code and it works fine outside of the function.

Specifically the following code works fine in a PS file, right click, run selection.

```
$partitionKey1 = "partitionKey1"
$RowKey = $productID
$draw = Get-AzTableRow -table $cloudTable -partitionKey $partitionKey1 -RowKey $RowKey
# increment the number of tickets sold.
[int]$draw.tickets_sold += $line_item.quantity
$draw | Update-AzTableRow -table $CloudTable
```

But when i put it in the functions PS file it blows up.

```
ERROR: The property 'tickets_sold' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
  
Exception             : 
Type        : System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException
ErrorRecord : 
     Exception             : 
         Type    : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException
         Message : The property 'tickets_sold' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
         HResult : -2146233087
```

Does anyone see anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: _it works fine outside of the function_ means that once you wrap this in a function, some variables are unknown to that function. Could be `$productID` or `$CloudTable`. Please show us the function and how you call it

Comment: One of the variables used in the call is above already.  the other one isnt' and as soon as I checked why, i realised I'd make a mistake in gathering it from the Request. Thats a reminder to check the basics more than once and maybe to step away from the monitor a bit more often, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Summarize from the comments:

The problem was caused by one variable is gathered from the request, and when wrap the code in function, the variable is missing. So it led to `$draw` can't be got, and it shows `The property 'tickets_sold' cannot be found` error message.